# React- Materialize Radio button is not working properly

Tags: reactjs, material-design

am new to ReactJs and react-materialize. I created two input element type Radio with the help of react-materialize in my component. Both are rendering in DOM.

I click on 1st radio option is selected and triggering onChange event. After clicking the second option isn't selected on the first click but work fine at second time click. After clicking on any option both are not triggering event.

"react": "^16.5.2"
"react-materialize": "^2.4.8",

This issue same like and tried with this solution, but not working https://github.com/react-materialize/react-materialize/issues/422

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'; 
import {Input} from 'react-materialize';
class Section extends Component {
    render() {
         return (
           <div className="row">
                {
                   this
                    .props
                    .options
                    .map((option, index) => (
                        <div key={index} className="col s6">
                            <Input
                                type="radio"
                                name="report"
                                className="with-gap"
                                value={option.value}
                                checked = {this.props.selected}
                                key={index}
                                onChange={(e)=>console.log(e.target.value)}
                                label={option.label}/>
                        </div>
                    ))
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

I expect the output of both radio options should be selected at first click and call onChange at all click. Please correct me what mistake I did.